# Zipfile with no parent folder

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I am able to compress files into a single zip file, however when I open the zip file the contents always include a "parent folder" which has the same exact name as the zip file itslef.

I'm simply trying to create a zip file that contains no folders at all.

Current: abc.zip > abc (folder) > files

Looking for: abc.zip > files

```
def create_zip(file_name, file_dir):
    """
    Function to create zip archive
    """
    os.chdir(file_dir)
    zipfiles_list = ['csv', 'txt']
    file_name_part = file_name
    zip_name = '{0}.zip'.format(file_name_part)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as 
    zip_archive:
        for file_extension in zipfile_list:
            full_file_path = '{0}.{1}'.format(file_name_part, file_extension)
            zip_archive.write(full_file_path, basename(full_file_path))
```

Is this possible? I've seen that if I rename the zip file after it's created, it will still extract contents into a folder that matches the zip file name.

[Original zip extracts to abc folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak5m0.png)

[Renamed same exact zip and contents extract to folder with new name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0ibq.png)

Comment: Please say exactly how you are extracting the files in the question.

Comment: i run your code but i did not see any folder (Win10)

Comment: I was simply opening the zip file by double clicking or right clicking and selecting 'open'.  Mac OS.

Comment: Voting to close since the problem turned out to be a simple oversight and has nothing to do with what the question asks. If you had constructed and provided a [mcve] in the first place, you would see the problem even before asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have a mistake in a word '**zipfiles**': `for file_extension in zipfile_list:` (without 's' in the end).

It have to be `for file_extension in zipfiles_list:`.

Than I run your code in Win7x86 - it is OK, no inner folder (python 3.6.6).

Tried it on Win 10x64 - same.

Xubuntu 18.04 x64 - same, without folder.

Here is my script:

```
from os.path import basename 
from os import path
import os
import zipfile

# current directory
script_dir = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))

def create_zip(file_name, file_dir):
    """
    Function to create zip archive
    """
    os.chdir(file_dir)
    zipfiles_list = ['csv', 'txt']
    file_name_part = file_name
    zip_name = '{0}.zip'.format(file_name_part)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_archive:
        for file_extension in zipfiles_list:
            full_file_path = '{0}.{1}'.format(file_name_part, file_extension)
            zip_archive.write(full_file_path, basename(full_file_path))

create_zip("first", script_dir)
```

In a directory with script there two files: first.txt and first.csv. After runing this scrip I do have zip file first.zip with two files inside: first.txt and first.csv.